# Jenkins - How to make a child wait for both parents?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 5 jobs in Jenkins:

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjph7.png)

"E" is executed only after both parents(C & D) have completed their builds.

How do I trigger the child job only after both parents jobs?

Note: I want to make sure that "E" executes only once.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pipeline for it.
Run jobs C and D in parallel , once both complete run job E.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any case where C or D would be ran independently of the other and then E being ran? If not, then you could just add a post-build downstream for D from C and downstream E from D therefore the pipeline would get built C->D->E in that order.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I was trying to avoid running jobs in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `Up & Down stream` project setup with your project order. Use `General` => `Advanced` => `Block build when upstream project is building` option to your `Project E` so that it will wait until `Project C & D` builds are done. You can have the same for `Project C & D` also. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your suggestion but it didn't accomplish all my "requests". Imagine if "D" completes his execution firstly than "B", it will trigger "E" because "C" it's not building neither in the Build Queue.